# MySQL Procedure Create Fails when Using CONCAT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation

I've run into a problem with MySQL v.5.0.091-log. This database is housed by my client's provider (1&1) so I have no control over the version, nor over the phpMyAdmin (version 2.6.4-pl3) they provide us to use.

My firm uses stored procedures and functions most the time for efficiency and security. I wrote a sproc that works fine on our local development database, but the moment I try to add it to the test or production MySQL servers at the host, the create statement fails. Since the version of phpMyAdmin they provide does not work with stored procedures, we have our own interface that allows up to maintain them. It has been tested and is not the cause of the problem.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `objectGetOpenObjectsInfo`()
BEGIN

SELECT     bldgobjects.objectId, CONCAT(objectrentinfo.shortDesc,'<br/>',bldginfo.address, ', ',bldginfo.city) AS objTitle,  
   CONCAT(imagelist.fileDirectory, imagelist.fileName) AS objImg
FROM         objectrentinfo INNER JOIN
                      bldgobjects ON objectrentinfo.objectId = bldgobjects.objectId INNER JOIN
                      bldginfo ON bldgobjects.bldgId = bldginfo.bldgId INNER JOIN
                      bldgimages ON bldgobjects.bldgId = bldgimages.bldgId INNER JOIN
                      imagelist ON bldgimages.imageId = imagelist.imageId
WHERE     (objectrentinfo.isOpen = 1) AND (imagelist.imgType = 1)
ORDER BY bldginfo.address;

END
```

The problem is specifically the CONCAT statements. As long as they are in the procedure, the create statement will not execute. As soon as change it to:

```
SELECT     bldgobjects.objectId, objectrentinfo.shortDesc, bldginfo.address, bldginfo.city,  
           imagelist.fileDirectory, imagelist.fileName
```

the create statement executes and I have my sproc. I have looked it over and over, most likely its some tiny syntax error I overlooked but I am at a loss. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance and appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with delimiters in phpmyadmin, try another MySQL client if it is possible or try this code, without BEGIN-END clause -

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `objectGetOpenObjectsInfo`()
  SELECT bldgobjects.objectId
       , CONCAT(objectrentinfo.shortDesc, '<br/>', bldginfo.address, ', ', bldginfo.city) AS objTitle
       , CONCAT(imagelist.fileDirectory, imagelist.fileName) AS objImg
  FROM
    objectrentinfo
  INNER JOIN bldgobjects
    ON objectrentinfo.objectId = bldgobjects.objectId
  INNER JOIN bldginfo
    ON bldgobjects.bldgId = bldginfo.bldgId
  INNER JOIN bldgimages
    ON bldgobjects.bldgId = bldgimages.bldgId
  INNER JOIN imagelist
    ON bldgimages.imageId = imagelist.imageId
  WHERE
    (objectrentinfo.isOpen = 1) AND (imagelist.imgType = 1)
  ORDER BY
    bldginfo.address;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tired the above but unfortunately still the same problem. The only error message I am getting is that one over the world generic where it says to check the documentation. On my own machines this works with the interface so I am thinking it has to do with the MySQL version perhaps?